Derivative of max over a parameter
Suppose I have a function that is defined as the maximum over a 2 parameter function.
$$f(x) = \max_{y} g(x,y)$$
Is there a formula for the derivative of $f$ with respect to $x$?

In the following page there is a note on the derivation of argmax: https://rfsantacruz.github.io/files/pdfs/TR2016_argmin.pdf
I can write the function f(x) as g(x,argmax_y g(x,y)) and proceed using the chain rule but I was hoping for something better

f(x) may not be differentiable in general

Yes, there is. However, I think chain rule is the only "formula".
Let $y^*(x)$ be the solution to $\max_yg(x,y)$, so $f(x)=g(x,y^*(x))$.
So, $$\frac{df}{dx}=\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}\frac{d(x)}{dx}+\frac{\partial g}{\partial y}\frac{d(y^*(x))}{dx}$$
Since $y^*(x)$ is the argument to the optimal solution, it implies $g_y(x,y^*(x))=0$, so we get:
$$\frac{df}{dx}=\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}$$ where $y=y^*(x)$.
Another method to tackle the problem:
Find $y^*(x)$ such that $g(x,y^*(x))$ is the optimal solution, then substitute $y=y^*(x)$ into $g$, so there is no need to use chain rule, that is differentiate $f$ directly with respect to $x$. To illustrate it, let $g=-x^2-y^2$, then $$f(x)=\max_yg(x,y)=\max_y(-x^2-y^2)=-x^2$$then we can different it directly without chain rule.

Now that I see the answer, I wonder isn't the last term 0? since for y*(x) we have g_y(x,y*(x)) = 0 ???

Ah yes, you are right, I will edit my answer now.
